# Unity Crashes when using WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash

My code is as follow

```
using (WWW _commonFilesDOwnloader = WWW.LoadFromCacheOrDownload ("https://example.com/Testing/bundle", 1)) {
        while (!_commonFilesDOwnloader.isDone) {
            Debug.Log ("Progress " + _commonFilesDOwnloader.progress);

            yield return null;
        }

        if (_commonFilesDOwnloader.error == null) {
            //file downloaded completely

            AssetBundle _comonBundle = _commonFilesDOwnloader.assetBundle;

            AssetBundleRequest _comonBundleReq = _comonBundle.LoadAllAssetsAsync ();

            yield return _comonBundleReq;

            Debug.Log ("Done Loading");

        }
    }
```

It download the whole content but it crashes inside if statement, where exactly that I don't know.
Can someone tell me what wrong I am doing in above code?

Comment: What operating system?  What version of Unity?

Comment: I am on Mac and using Unity 5.3.2 It crashes sometime, but when I run on my ios device it always crashes. I think the problem is with these line.. AssetBundleRequest _comonBundleReq = _comonBundle.LoadAllAssetsAsync ();

            yield return _comonBundleReq;

Comment: There are [hints](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/787716/using-loadfromcacheordownload-causes-ios-to-freeze.html) that this is an unresolved bug in Unity.